# Determine if a $95\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ is equal to a given set

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

So I need to decide if the following statement is true or false:
Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n \sim N(\theta,1)$.
Then a $95\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ is all of the values of $\theta$ that satisfies:
$$\left\{ \theta:0.025\leq\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}-\theta\right)}f\left(x\arrowvert\theta\right)dx\leq0.975\right\}$$
where the density function is:$$f\left(x\arrowvert\theta\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-\left(x-\theta\right)^{2}}{2}},-\infty<x<\infty$$

So my initial thought was that the statement is false because we know about CDF that
$\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}-\theta\right)}f\left(x\arrowvert\theta\right)dx=P\left(X\leq\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}-\theta\right)\right)=P\left(Z+\theta\leq\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}-\theta\right)\right)=P\left(Z\leq\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}-\theta\right)-\theta\right)$
and the inequality is true iff $z_{0.025}\leq\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X}-\theta\right)-\theta\leq z_{0.975}$ from here we get $\bar{X}-\frac{z_{0.975}}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\theta+\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\bar{X}+\frac{z_{0.975}}{\sqrt{n}}$.
but becuase $X\sim N\left(\theta,1\right)$ we know that $$CI_{95\%}\left(\theta\right)=\left\{ \bar{X}-\frac{z_{0.975}}{\sqrt{n}}\leq\theta\leq\bar{X}+\frac{z_{0.975}}{\sqrt{n}}\right\}$$  and intervals are not equal so we can declare the statement as false but it seems that is not  the right answer (it's a question from past exam and the answer which was similar to mine was marked as incorrect so possibly the statement may be true) and I can't think of a new way to tackle this so I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Minor issues: You are using $\theta$ in two different senses in "a $95\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ is all of the values of $\theta$ that satisfies ...", which may be confusing.  Meanwhile $f\left(x\mid\theta\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-\left(x-\theta\right)^{2}}{2}}$ is a density not a CDF.  Why do you say the intervals are not the same (not that they have to be: all you need is that the intervals have a $95\%$ probability of covering the true parameter value and there may be different methods of constructing intervals which both achieve this)?